# (Discord Bot) on_raw_reaction_add(payload) problems (Ticket System)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey I'm developing a Discord Bot with Python. Here is the documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

I would ask a question. I making a discord bot in Python and I need help:

1. Is it possible to make function in discord bot that I can relate to? I would like to include the entire ticketing system in event on_raw_reaction_add. Is this even possible? If this is not possible, then how to refer, for example, to a given ticket ?
2. I would like to include a condition in the ticketing system. When creating a ticket, the user gets the rank "A". If he already has this rank, the bot will write to him that he has already created a ticket and will not be able to create another ticket. Does anyone have an idea how can I check if a user has a rank? I know that @ command.has_role exists, but this will not work for a condition.

This is the my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
        message_id = payload.message_id
        if message_id == 701490140110913568:
                guild_id = payload.guild_id
                guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
                if payload.emoji.name == 'koperta':
                                print("zlotek")
                                channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
                                message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
                                user = client.get_user(payload.user_id)
                                emoji = client.get_emoji(700845595103068211)
                                await message.remove_reaction(emoji, user)
                                name = '✅ OPENED TICKETS ✅'
                                category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name=name)
                                overwrites = overwrites = {
                                guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
                                guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
                                }
                                await guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket-0001', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
                                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='A')
                                member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
                                await member.add_roles(role)
```

Thank you for all forms of help. You are the best

Comment: Have you tried data storage such as using JSON and checking the JSON file for the user's data, when a ticket is created you could dump the data in the JSON file with some information such as user id, and maybe a unique identifier for that ticket? I made a ticket system and that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```py
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):

  if user.id != 858515419363147807:
    guild = reaction.message.guild
    global confirmation
    channelexsits = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name=user.name.lower().replace("#",""))
    if channelexsits:
      None
    else:
      botrolle = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=858515574992404491)

    if reaction.emoji == '️':
      category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=888944156062396426)
      channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name=f"╠▹{user.name}", category=category)
      await channel.set_permissions(user,read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
      embed = discord.Embed(title=f"`{user.guild.name}`", description=f"> Hallo, {user.mention}!\n> Du hast ein Ticket erstellt wie kann ich dir helfen?\n\n> Um das Ticket zu schließen drücke .", color=random.choice (Farben))
      embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{user.guild.icon_url}")
      embed.set_footer(text=f"{user.guild.name}",icon_url=f"{user.guild.icon_url}")
      embed.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
      message = await channel.send(embed=embed)
      await message.add_reaction('')

    if reaction.emoji == '': 
      embed = discord.Embed(title=f"`{user.guild.name}`", description=f"{user.mention} Willst du dein Ticket wirklich schließen?", color=random.choice (Farben))
      embed.set_footer(text=f"{user.guild.name}",icon_url=f"{user.guild.icon_url}")
      embed.timestamp = datetime.utcnow() 
      confirmation = await reaction.message.channel.send(embed=embed)
      await confirmation.add_reaction('✅')
      await confirmation.add_reaction('❌')

    if reaction.emoji == '✅':
      await reaction.message.channel.delete(reason=None)

    if reaction.emoji == '❌':
      message = await reaction.message.channel.fetch_message(confirmation.id)
      await message.delete()  

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def close(ctx, *, grund:str):
  membert = discord.utils.get(ctx.channel.members, discriminator=f"{ctx.channel.name[0:4]}")
  embed = discord.Embed(title="`Hinweis!`", color=random.choice (Farben))

  if ctx.channel.category.name == "Tickets":
    filename = f"{ctx.channel.name}.txt"

    with open(filename, "w") as file:
      async for msg in ctx.channel.history(limit=None,oldest_first=True):
        zeit = msg.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M")
        file.write(f"{zeit} - {msg.author} >> {msg.clean_content}\n")

    with open(filename, "rb") as file:
      embed.set_author(name=f"{ctx.guild.name}")
      embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{ctx.guild.icon_url}")
      embed.add_field(name=f"Dein Ticket wurde von {ctx.author}, geschlossen", value=f"Grund: {grund}")
      embed.set_footer(text="Wann ist das passiert?")
      embed.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
      await membert.send(embed=embed)
      await membert.send("TRANSKRIPT", file=discord.File(file,filename=filename))    

    os.remove(f"{filename}")
    await ctx.channel.delete()
```